# How to encapsulate Between statement in SQL server

Tags: sql, between

How to encapsulate Between statement in SQL server.

I have a lot of code to refactor that has long list of where clauses with the same Between statement that have magic numbers and I want to refactor it. It is possible to encapsulate the BETWEEN.

Example: The query has something similar like this and there is not possibility of join this just a basic example to show that I would like to have something in the WHERE that is not repeating the BETWEEN

```
SELECT ...
FROM Table0
WHERE Id BETWEEN 3456 AND 15500;

...

SELECT ...
FROM Table1
WHERE Id BETWEEN 3456 AND 15500;

...
SELECT ...
FROM Table2
WHERE Id BETWEEN 3456 AND 15500;
```

Comment: Can you refer to what you mean by encapsulate in this context? If you don't want to continuously reuse the same hard-coded values, consider storing them in variables and using the variables in your queries. This would essentially allow you to define them in a single area.

Comment: The encapsulation that I am looking maybe is not possible because I am thinking in term of Java and C# to organize the code. I want something with the same effect that in C# changing a long if(x>3456 && x <15500) for if(IsValidId) where IsValid = > (x>3456 && x <15500). So having a WHERE IsValid. This kind of the encapsulation that I am looking for but not sure if SQL allows this idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a function you can do it.

```
create function dbo.isValid(val int)
returns int
as
begin
if val BETWEEN 3456 AND 15500
   return 1
return 0
end
```

And obvious usage:

```
select * from table1
where dbo.isValid(id) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Rion said either create variables or use a seperated table

```
CREATE TABLE check_range
    ("range_id" int, "begin" int, "end" int)
;

INSERT INTO check_range
    ("range_id", "begin", "end")
VALUES
    (1, 3456, 15500)
;
```

Then your query should be

```
SELECT ...
FROM Table0
CROSS JOIN check_range cr
WHERE Id BETWEEN cr.begin AND cr.end;
```

Comment: This is interesting solution not exactly what I am looking for but good alternative

Answer (score 0):

You might try

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT ....
  FROM   table1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ....
  FROM   table2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ....
  FROM   table3
)
WHERE Id BETWEEN 3456 AND 15500;
```